# Repeating alarm not triggering in android at every 12 am daily

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I am using the following code to set a repeating alarm in android to trigger at every 12am but it not getting trigger even at one.
I need this alarm to trigger from next day 12 am hence I added one date in calendar object.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,00);

        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
        Utils.printLog("date from repeating alarm "+calendar.getTime());
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent startPIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 15, startIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarmMgr != null) {
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, startPIntent);
        }
```

I tested by breakpoint and found that `alarmMgr` is not null on setting it.
Also the `RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class` is working.

Comment: Do not use `setRepeating` . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651310/4168607. Set Exact Alarm each time set alarm for next event .

Comment: Even if you get it successful on emulator, it will not work in real world as 99% operating systems are MIUI, OxygenOS, ColorOs, FuntouchOs all are chinese modified ROMs, never allows to run it

Comment: i had a problem like this. i set an intent filter in manifest and called Intent intent = new Intent("com.mypackage.MY_ACTION); then intent.setClass(context, RepeatingAlarmReceiver.class); it worked when i set an action in intent filter and made intent like that

Comment: https://github.com/copypasteearth/Powerball-MegaMillions/blob/master/app/src/main/java/powerball/apps/jacs/powerball/AlarmSettingManager.java

Comment: @JRowan unfortunately  my broadcast receiver has no problems, it works perfectly on calling by other ways.
Main problem is alarm is not triggering.