# Alarm Manager not running? Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, repeatingalarm

Any ideas why my alarm manager will not run?
I have been fiddling around for hours and one of them is running but the other isn't and I can't find a solution.

```
Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startHours);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startMinutes);
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(WelcomeScreen.this, DNDAlarm.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(WelcomeScreen.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47651310/4168607) might help .

Comment: So how do I get around that?

Comment: Add your Manifest file here also

Comment: That might just be my problem. I didnt include the Broadcast receiver in the manifest. Ill try that

Comment: That was the problem thanks. Its running up to 1 minute late due to inexact timings. but i think that will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the Broadcast receiver in the manifest file, here's an example from the docs:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```